# VMware Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible, but I don’t have Hyper-V

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I am having trouble booting up Remnux on my AWS VM. Though the platform is set to Windows 2016, Whoer identifies it as Win10. However, running the `slmgr /dlv` command resulted in Windows(R) ServerDatacenter edition. Inside the VM, I am attempting to set up a Remnux VM with VMWare Workstation Pro, but when I try to boot Remnux, I receive the error message: ‘’VMWare Workstation and Hyper-V are not compatible. Remove the Hyper-V role from the system before running VMWare Workstation.’’ Oddly, Hyper-V Server doesn't have a checkmark in roles in server manager. When I attempted to disable Hyper-V command in PowerShell, I received this result: `Feature name Microsoft-Hyper-V-Hypervisor is unknown`. What steps should I take to resolve this issue?

[Here is a screenshot of the Hyper-V role not appearing in the server manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xd7Ch.jpg)

P.S I tried rebooting vm,but got same result.